# Type level operations for labelled tuple

Tags: typescript, type-level-computation, typescript4.0

I'd like to do something similar to below with labelled tuples and wondering it this posible in TS4 yet

```
type stringProperties<T extends {}> = {[k in keyof T]: string}
```

This would mean that I could create a type
`[foo: string, bar: string, baz:string]` from `[foo: boolean, bar: number, baz: any]`

At the moment I'm missing the way to generically capture the label (its not present in keyof) and not sure how to add another label:type pair to an existing tuple type.

I'm aware of the technique below to prepend to an unlabelled tuple but in this case the label will be set as `first`.

```
export type Prepend<E, T extends any[]> =
    ((first: E, ...args: T) => any) extends ((...args: infer U) => any)
    ? U
    : never
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a type that translates the properties of a type into a tuple type such that each tuple element corresponds to a property and is labeled by that property's key or do you want the reverse?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mapped tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to just change element types. Their [labels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#labeled-tuple-elements) are preserved:

```
type T1 = stringProperties<[foo: boolean, bar: number, baz: any]> 
// [foo: string, bar: string, baz: string]
```

While you [cannot directly extract](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26019) the function parameter names, adding a new labeled element is still possible with [TS 4.0 variadic tuple types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#variadic-tuple-types):

```
type Prepend<E extends [unknown], A extends any[]> = [...E, ...A]
type Append<E extends [unknown], A extends any[]> = [...A, ...E]
// ... extend to your needs

type T2 = Prepend<[customLabel: string], A> 
// [customLabel: string, foo: boolean, bar: number, baz: any]
type T3 = Append<[customLabel: string], A> 
// [foo: boolean, bar: number, baz: any, customLabel: string]
type T4 = Prepend<[customLabel: string], stringProperties<A>> // or mix it up
// [customLabel: string, foo: string, bar: string, baz: string]
```

... And later on use types as function parameters:

```
function foo(...args: T4) {}
// function foo(customLabel: string, foo: string, bar: string, baz: string): void
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAzsBOBLAdgcwArwPaXsREMAPACpQQAewEyAJjFAN4C%20AfFALxMDaA1lCii8IILADMoJALoAuWAhSpmAKFCQoAQU5RuYrFjkAjfQBsIAQ2QAaKIfPw5yAK4BbQxHg27ALzmWQUsqq4NAkAIzacEhomDge%20IREuvpGphbWtvaOru6emb5Q-lLsygD0pTp6BvLRqF5ZNYr1BVGKgcHqmBCQdEQAouRUNPQ6Tsi8yFgA7shSNlqU1HQM-tzF2twAdNt9NtubGoFq0BpgPbT9g0sj3GMT07PzV8MryCBr7Fxb2xp7O%203HSQAJm0XXOSQAxk44FgXAAZczuExyVpoOaadjlHRQmHwxEQZGNNA2KqpLBmSz1BxQZxuDzNPxvI4hSQAZm0p3B3BxwFhCKRKIUaPmmIqyWqxnJ6Sp2TpeR8jJANh5fPxhNRqECWKw8CgLkQFAEwCgTjAHVCABZQfBusNIdDeXiBUTNTYNbFcAliBpWKLsQ7Vc6NSSUi6ZWH8oLau0xGMIfgsMgoFUABT7eyoGByEgWgCUTBUWNjyHjiETyf0KZVToJUaaFeqwcy1KbCpdubkADcsIhaEA)