# How to infer first element of a tuple as a tuple type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm unable to properly infer the first type of a tuple of arbitrary length as a tuple type, in order to maintain its label:

```
type First1<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer FIRST, ...any[]] ? FIRST : never

type test1 = First1<[a: number, b: boolean, c: string]> // number


type First2<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer FIRST, ...any[]] ? [FIRST] : never

type test2 = First2<[a: number, b: boolean, c: string]> // [number] <-- obv no label


type First3<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer FIRST, any, ...any[]] ? FIRST : never

type test3 = First3<[a: number, b: boolean, c: string]> // unknown[] <-- I tried ahah
```

Any ideas?
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-dev.20220514&ssl=18&ssc=86&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgZ2AHgCpQgD2BAdgEwSjlxAG0BdAPigF4p0scCiySQAaKAOl4EtcAMwgAnWAEEAyqgpQA-BOlQAXFFwQAbqIBQ20JCg4kMOrEQo2q3AFcAtgCNRXe6vsB7NwBsIJLgGNVJBEBAHNqKAB6CKgyFyh3Lx9cf0DgYNww3T1waAAxPhEkAEY0DGw8QmJSShp6RnKWGIFhMVyASQAlaS5ebnZKWQV2rvQrTR1sgyNgItN8wpnkSzU7RxFnVw9vXygAqCDQ8KiVhwnJvIKkACZSpgqifvC6suZKsmbRKGHunl5HwZi3xkKjU4xEun00GmVzml2AN2WNlO63im0SOz2BwyR2iZCRa1kyAAtESoG57Bo1G4oJ44I5PFlIV84QBmW4NSqPWoMF73GK9D6tTo-dg9P7VCgAoEg9RacHnQwQJAs2ELNmI1ZOVHxLZJFL7NKHGjHay4ADWuDcAHdcJQoMTSW1DMEIPhiAALODuoA)

Expected result: `[a: number]`

Comment: So the result you want is basically to get `[a: number]` as the type hint?

Comment: My recursive attempt gets the dreaded *"Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)"* error: `type First4<T extends any[]> = T extends [any] ? T : First4<[...T, any]>;`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes `[a: number]` is the expected result

Comment: I believe that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69973072/how-can-you-ensure-that-tuple-element-labels-are-preserved) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189351/type-level-operations-for-labelled-tuple/64194372#64194372) you will find all information you need about using labels

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following approach works for your example code:

```
type First<T extends any[]> = T extends [any, ...infer R] ?
    T extends [...infer F, ...R] ? F : never : never

type Test = First<[a: number, b: boolean, c: string]>
// type Test = [a: number]
```

The idea is to take the tuple type `T` and infer from it the tuple `R` corresponding to everything after the first element.  Once `R` is fixed, we can ask the compiler to split `T` into two tuples, the last of which is `R`.  This returns a tuple containing just the first element, with the label intact.

---

Of course there are edge cases which won't work, like [optional tuple elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types), and [rest elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types) including [leading and middle rest elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types):

```
type X = First<[a?: number, b?: boolean, c?: string]>; // never
type Y = First<[...a: number[], b: boolean, c: string]> // never
type Z = First<[a: number, ...b: boolean[], c: string]> // unknown[]
```

I don't know that there's a good way of doing this that has no edge cases.  According to GitHub comments like [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43020#issuecomment-790994531), preserving tuple labels through type transformations isn't guaranteed to work in all cases, so a partially functioning solution might be as good as it gets.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIDECWAnAzqAPAFVtAHqNAHYAmqsAhkeANoC6AfLALyw76Gnk1XgA0sAHTDERAGbRksAEp1YAfmCxlbXAWJlYNYYNESp8ATtkKEsAFywi0AG6SLV25JAQYbaOhYIU6DD0tEAK4AtgBGkgKhlqEA9jEANtBUAgDGlujIogDmjMAA9HmwrnBYHqBe-lYh4ch0LlBwABpeSGiYPPIB1RGwoZ29cYnJsCn9GdmMANywBY52yGANsACaLT7tOhRdYZL0kdGDSUSp6aCZRDlMs9bzi24AWmttfltVO8hGwlEDCUd7I6dzpcZoVAkQANZEGIAdyI9BAQA)

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to make it work for optional params: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgJwM7AIJICoFcwBsIA8GUEAHsBAHYAmSUCEAhtQPaW4hSOUgDaAugD4oAXijEyFGnQbM2HKAIBQUKAH4olCADcICFVABc4kuSq16TVu069uINQBooAOjdxKAMz3jUASQAZfgMNCTNpSzkbRTcXD28EKAAJAFFUABFnWIx-IJDktPSDYy1dfVUSnT0AbiUlUEgoChRRWEQUdGw8Qjs1EqwAWwAjPWchvs1BkYQhIA

Answer (score 1):

My current solution:

```
type Init<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer INIT, any] ? INIT : never;

type FirstAsTuple<T extends any[]> = T extends [any]
  ? T extends [...infer F]
    ? F
    : never
  : FirstAsTuple<Init<T>>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=27&pln=1&pc=1&ts=next#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgS2AHgCpQgD2BOATAZygEM4QBtAXQD4oBeKdLHfI8gOk4TgDMIAnWADkYqADQkylKAH5hoqAC4ocCADcBAbgBQ20JCgAxBPwLAAggVQBXMABsIaDNlyFJFGvUbOWb8qRBKbShZb2ZXNk52bj5BQyCQkLlDYMTlVQ1+VOVjUwsrWwdkeCQ0amodXX1oHDMvXLNLG3tHf3TrAFsAIwEJLuUugHtBh1IJAGNlM35uAHNPAHoFqDaVTp7+SiA)

Waiting if anyone knows a non-recursive trick.